# Как получить строки не через SELECT, а через EXEC хранимые процедуры?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

**USE [BASE]
GO
EXEC [dbo].[Operation] 123456** - такой запрос через mssql сервер напрямую строки выдает, а как через dpo также сделать?

```
if($_POST['Id_oper']){
  $Id_oper = $_POST['Id_oper'];

  $stmt = $db->prepare("EXEC Operation $Id_oper");

  while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY)) 
  { 
    $user = array(
        'text'=>$row['text'],
        'text2'=>$row['text2'],
        'text3'=>$row['text3'],
        'text4'=>$row['text4']
   );
   $car[] = $user;  
    
  } 
} 
 echo json_encode(array("users" => $car));
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: после подготовки запрос выполнить надо. и fetchAll там еще есть чтобы циклы не гонять